# Android VideoView playing URL with "307 Temporary Redirect"

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have one application were i am using VideoView to play a streaming video URL.

My URL redirects to another URL when we send request to and i am not able to play this video URL using VideoView.

I  request this url from PC browser i see in FireBug that URL is getting Temporary Redirect to another location, is it that video view does not handle redirection.